# Run over a list of directory of CSVs and execute a python script

Tags: python, csv, nltk, glob

I have a folder with CSVs and I would like to run the same script on all files, and then output a text for every CSV that carries the same name. I know you can do it with OS and Glob, but I'm fairly new to Python and I haven't done this kind of work.

Here is the script I am using to clean up the CSVs.

```
import logging
import csv
import sys
import simplejson
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from collections import defaultdict

stoplist = stopwords.words('dutch')


f = open('1949.csv') #changefilename here
csv_f = csv.reader(f, delimiter ='\t')
text_content = []

for row in csv_f:
    text_content.append(row[0])

#remove stopwords and tokenize
texts = [[word for word in document.lower().split() if word not in stoplist] for document in text_content]

newDoc = [[word for word in document if len(word) > 3 ]
        for document in texts]


f = open('output.txt', 'w')
simplejson.dump(newDoc, f)
f.close()
```

How can I rewrite this script to run over a list CSVs?

Comment: If you use Python 2.6 or above, `simplejson` could be replaced by the `json` module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand what exactly your question is.
Since you mention OS and ask something about a list of files (as opposed to just one file), maybe you're looking for something like this:

```
    filesInDir = os.listdir(<path_to_dir>)
    for fname in filesInDir:
        #<put your code in a function and do your CSV magic here>
        # when done, write to output
        name, extension = os.path.splitext(fname)
        outputTxt = name + '.txt'
        f = open(outputTxt, 'w')
        simplejson.dump(newDoc, f)
        f.close()
```

You may want to include some checks to make sure you are passing in csv (and not any other files that may also be in the folder passed to os.listdir).

Not sure if this was what you were after though...?